# Eclipse path issue of 'Generate Gradle Guild files'

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, migration

I trying to convert my android Eclipse project to Android Studio project. 
I updated the Android SDK Tools to 24.0.2, and export by clicking 'File > Export... > Android > Generate Gradle build files > Next > Next > Select Project(s)+lib(s) > Next > Finish'.

I can export build.gradle, setting.gradle, gradle(folder) ...
but all the exported files are in my 'Documents' folder not in the android project workspace.

Eclipse will auto generate 'Project root' e.g. '/User/usernaem xxxx/Documents' after select the project need to export.

**How can I change the 'Project root' generated by Eclipse?**

And I tried move those files: build.gradle, setting.gradle, gradle ... to a new folder
- updated "lasspath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'" in build.gradle
- updated "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip"  in gradle-wrapper.properties
then import to Android Studio but fail (without error but project content not showing).

**How can put the android studio project in old project workspace or in new folder?**

Many thanks.